# maximum number of tabs for UITabBarController without moreViewController

Tags: ios, uitabbarcontroller, uitabbar

Short of actually creating a UITabBarController and performing the relevant experiment, does iOS have a programmatic way of getting the maximum number of tabs that could show up in the tabBarController, without a "more" tab?

This would be highly helpful for some cross-platform work I'm doing.

Comment: @rmaddy is right about the counts.  The only way I can imagine getting these programatically would be to add tabs in a loop on an offscreen tab vc, looking for the more tab.  Otherwise, I think you can safely assume that the constants will remain good until another form factor change.

Comment: AFAIK there is no programmatic way, but 5 is the limit. Anyway, uitabbar is for ios, if you are working on cross-platform use another thing for other platforms, not ios like uitabbar

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The most is 5 (on an iPhone, 8 on an iPad). When you add a sixth you get the 1st four plus a More tab with the other two. This can't be changed using a standard `UITabBarController`.

Search github or other resources. There may be drop in replacement classes that will let you have more tabs shown at once.