# Change width of tab in UITabBarController to adjust the sixth tab

Tags: ios, swift, uitabbarcontroller, uitabbar

I need six tabs in tab bar controller. When I add the sixth tab more tab was created and fifth and sixth tab is not shown. How can I decrease the width of item so that it gets adjusted to show all six tabs.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20403971/maximum-number-of-tabs-for-uitabbarcontroller-without-moreviewcontroller it could be helpful probably

Comment: @EricAya He sais "i need six tabs in tab bar controller". I think it's clear, even if the question isn't the best one, it's clear

Comment: Possible duplicate of [maximum number of tabs for UITabBarController without moreViewController](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20403971/maximum-number-of-tabs-for-uitabbarcontroller-without-moreviewcontroller)

Comment: I don't think an NSTabBarController or whatever prefix tabBarController exists. I know it's not such a clean question, but with a bit of effort it's understandable @EricAya

Comment: @LucaD'Alberti Can you suggest some replacement classes?

Comment: @Sanoop your own-built solution I think here is better. I don't actually know if there is something outside

Answer (score 0):

```
//Swift #3
class TabBarViewController: UITabBarController, UITabBarControllerDelegate {  

    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {  
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)
    self.tabBar.itemWidth = your width 
     //(self.tabBar.frame.width) / (numberOfItems
    } 
  }
```