# How to show six TabBarItem in UITabBar

Tags: ios, swift, user-interface, uitabbarcontroller, uitabbar

Can I show six TabBarItem in UITabBar, I try to resize TabBarItem but it can't.
[uitabbar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YaZOn.png)

Comment: Not on an iPhone, only an iPad.

Comment: I saw facebook can be done or it not UITabBar.

Comment: Try it. What happens? It might work on bigger phones. The older, smaller phones definitely only allowed 5 tabs.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/a/20404273. You can have 8 tabs on iPad, BTW.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With default `UITabBarController` you can not because it will add `More` tab like shown below:

[image]

and you need to click on `More` tab to show another options.

But you can use third party library like [AZTabBarController](https://github.com/Minitour/AZTabBarController) which will populate all six options as shown below:

[image]

More libraries for tab bar can found [HERE](https://www.cocoacontrols.com/search?page=2&q=tabbar).

Answer (score 3):

You can achieve this by implementing a custom TabBarController. Here's an example that displays 6 tab bar items using a fake TraitCollection. However, it's important to note that this approach is not considered best practice according to Apple's design guidelines. For more information, please refer to Apple's Human Interface Guidelines for Tab Bars at https://developer.apple.com/design/human-interface-guidelines/tab-bars.

```
class CustomTabBarController: UITabBarController {

    override var traitCollection: UITraitCollection {
        let traitCollection = super.traitCollection
        let newTraitCollection = UITraitCollection(horizontalSizeClass: .regular)
        return UITraitCollection(traitsFrom: [traitCollection, newTraitCollection])
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is against "Human Interface Guidelines", but it is possible to have as many TabBarItems as you want using tabBar without tabBarController. You may lay out tabBar and items in storyboard. To respond to taps conform to UITabBarDelegate and implement at least `didSelectItem`.

```
import UIKit

class AdminViewController: UIViewController, UITabBarDelegate {
@IBOutlet weak var tabbar: UITabBar!
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    tabbar.delegate = self;
}

func tabBar(tabBar: UITabBar, didSelectItem item: UITabBarItem!) {
    print(item.tag);
    switch item.tag { // switching by tag is not required, just an option
    case 1:
     // segue or push or present something
    case 2: 
     // segue or push or present something
    default:
    break
    }    
}
```